# Is there a better way to say "go home to home"?

Tags: phrase-request

I am not sure if I am crazy, but "going home to home" sounds unidiomatic. By that, I mean going to every home like some people do every morning.

Here's an example:

> The milkman goes home to home to deliver milk in all of the houses he
>   was assigned.

Answer (score 4):

"Go from house to house" would be fine:

> They still go from house to house, questioning people.
>
> You go from house to house collecting subscriptions.
>
> That was the Christmas tradition- where you go from house to house collecting your presents.

It's true that *home* can mean a building, just like *house*. But those homes are not the milkman's ones (*someone's* home is the house or flat where *they* live). However, construction companies, for example, might say, "We build homes," not meaning their own homes. But in this case it sounds like homes for somebody, for people, for their customers. You don't need that kind of accent in your sentence about the milkman. So, "from house to house" is just fine.

Let me end by giving a few examples of "home to home:"

> Mason Geary was a foster kid who grew up bouncing from home to home. (from one *family* to another)
>
> We went form home to home and offered people the gospel of John. (again, from *family* to *family*)

Comment: +1 "from house to house" is the idiomatic option here. Another option that is less frequent than that, but more than "from home to home" is "from door to door."  link: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=from+house+to+house%2Cfrom+home+to+home%2C+from+door+to+door&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfrom%20house%20to%20house%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfrom%20home%20to%20home%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfrom%20door%20to%20door%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cfrom%20house%20to%20house%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfrom%20home%20to%20home%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfrom%20door%20to%20door%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @Katy good point. Thank you!